# Function to count the same key's in nested composed dict-list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, nested

I am trying to count the 'name' keys in this nested composed dict-list and i am getting 3 in place of 6 ,i think my problem is with the base case in the recursive function count_elem(tree)

```
def define_tree3():
    tree3 ={'name':'GAS','grade':0.8,'children':[{'name':'CSA','grade':0.5,'children':[{'name':'MB','grade':0.1},{'name':'TA','grade':0.6}]},{'name':'IIW','grade':0.9,'children':[None,{'name':'IP','grade':0.99}]}]}
    return tree3

#this fuction is to delete the given key from the given dict and retur the new dict
def delkey(dict1,key):
    d=dict(dict1)
    del d[key]
    return d

#this function is to count the numbers of 'name'
def count_elem(tree):
    if len(tree)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in tree:
            if i == None:
                return 0
            elif i == 'name':
                return 1+ count_elem(delkey(tree,i))
            elif i == 'grade':
                return count_elem(delkey(tree,i))
            elif i == 'children':
                for j in tree[i]:
                    if j == None:
                        continue
                    else:
                        return count_elem(j)

a=define_tree3()
print(count_elem(a))
```

Comment: `i think my problem is with the base case` - Why do you think that. When you printed stuff in the function is that where it seemed to go wrong?  If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: My suspicion is that delkey doesn’t do what you think it should. Perhaps you meant d=copy.deepcopy(dict1)

Comment: I have debugged the code and it is deleting the keys and the key i want to count is 'name' but some of the dicts don't have key 'children'  so when the keys have been deleted it will  return 0 and will not continue throw  the list

Comment: @jawad2000 There are 6 keys `"name"`, shouldn't be the correct answer 6 then?

Comment: Yes, sorry 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question. I just tried to solve it and used a different approach. Might be useful as a reference.

```py
tree3 = {'name':'GAS','grade':0.8,'children':[{'name':'CSA','grade':0.5,'children':[{'name':'MB','grade':0.1},{'name':'TA','grade':0.6}]},{'name':'IIW','grade':0.9,'children':[None,{'name':'IP','grade':0.99}]}]}

def count_name(entity):
    count = 0
    name = 'name'
    # print('\n')
    # print(count, entity)

    if type(entity) == dict:
        count += sum([key == name for key in entity.keys()])
    
        for value in entity.values():
            # print(count, value)

            if type(value) == list:
                count += sum([count_name(member) for member in value])

    return count

count_name(tree3)
```

Comment: Thx man i appreciate that, but my function should be with one parameter because this what's been asked to me

Comment: You can use it also only with a single parameter. I edited the code.

Comment: Amazing, you gave me an idea to get my code worked 

Comment: Can i get the name of the largest grade using the same recursive function?

Comment: You need to change it, but probably yes, you can. Basically, you look for 'grade' instead of 'name' and rewrite the `count += sum([key == name for key in entity.keys()])` so that it checks if the found grades are higher than what you have already stored. You also need to rewrite so it does not return a count but a sum.